# SO_TIMESTAMP and Packet Processing Latency with Container Networking

Tags: linux, docker, sockets, networking

### Problem

I want to track packet processing latency of the linux network stack for docker containers. From what I understand, the involvement of containers produces more overhead for a packet trying to reach a container because of passing through two kernels, the host machines kernel and the docker container kernel. This in turn should produce more latency and more kernel packet processing latency.

### Work So Far

I am running CentOS with docker, and I have used [this](https://vilimpoc.org/research/ku-latency/) to track the packet processing latency with SO_TIMESTAMP by returning a timestamp in the form of a `timeval` when the packet just leaves the NIC and enters the kernel. Then after `recvmsg` is called, the user space program then calls gettimeofday() and the difference between those two values is the packet processing latency. Running on CentOS with kernel version 3.10.xxx, I can achieve about ~100us of packet processing latency if just running the programs on hsot. However, when I run the same code in two docker containers, I get about the same packet processing latency.

### Question

The additional of a container and its own kernel stack, there should be an increase in packet processing latency, and my logic is that the program's SO_TIMESTAMP in the docker container only tells its own kernel to get a time stamp, when it enters the virtual "veth0" network interface card, and thus should only have software time stamping and a more inaccurate reading. But nonetheless, the system time between a container and the host should be the same, and the total packet processing latency should be ~200us. I am curious, is there a way to track the packet processing latency across both kernel stacks using SO_TIMESTAMP?

P.S Also, what is the best way to track the reverse, the TX stack, instead of the RX stack mentioned above.

Comment: Containers run on the host OS.  They do not have a separate kernel.  Maybe you are thinking of VMs.

Comment: @stark However, they should have their own network stack in terms of qdisc, and docker configured iptables. I know that unless the -net==host option is set, that a container has no way of viewing the physical interface of the host. Perhaps network stack is better phrase than kernel stack if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: The single kernel has a single network stack including a single instance of iptables. Typically, docker defines its own chains to isolate its own rules, but that's just syntax. The overhead added by a bridge and virtual interface is quite small, as you have discovered.